# vSphere says that the host is in maintenance mode... but it's not

Tags: vmware-vsphere

A user is trying to migrate a virtual machine from a datastore to another.

However during the migration wizard an error message prevents him from choosing the right operation:

[image: The host of the virtual machine is in maintenance mode. Migration cannot be performed when the host is in maintenance mode.]

The host is absolutely not in maintenance mode an I do not see this message when I repeat the same steps from my workstation.

We have different privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply read only permissions on the hosts of the cluster.